# Centralities in Weighted Networks

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I have a weighted, undirected network with five nodes, whose adjacency matrix is given by

```
A = {{0, 3, 7, 0, 0}, {3, 0, 6, 0, 0}, {7, 6, 0, 2, 1}, {0, 0, 2, 0, 
4}, {0, 0, 1, 4, 0}};
```

I've created a weighted graph using A as follows:

```
G = WeightedAdjacencyGraph[ReplacePart[A, {j_, j_} -> \[Infinity]], 
  VertexLabels -> "Name", VertexSize -> Automatic, 
  VertexLabelStyle -> Large]
```

I'm interested in computing various centrality measures, specifically degree, closeness, and betweenness. For the first, I entered

```
DegreeCentrality[G]
```

The result was {4, 4, 4, 4, 4}, which is incorrect given my positive, integer-valued weights, and instead corresponds to the degree centrality of a complete graph on five vertices.

1. I'm curious to know how I should go about computing the degree centrality for this graph.
2. Also, can the ClosenessCentrality and BetweennessCentrality commands be used for weighted graphs, and, if so, what basic approach do they take. For example, is betweenness based upon shortest distances (as described in Social Networks, v13, 1991,141-154), where we use the reciprocals of the edge weights)?

Comment: I don't know enough about graph theory to know, but is the fact that `IsomorphicGraphQ[G, CompleteGraph[5]]` returns `True` a bug?  If so, that might be the underlying issue.

Comment: @JasonB. The issue is that many builtins don't support weighted graphs. It was one of my primary motivations for starting IGraph/M.  It's not related to `IsomorhicGraphQ`.

Comment: @Szabolcs - I'm just noticing that graph constructed by `WeightedAdjacencyGraph` looks completely different from the `IGWeightedAdjacencyGraph` result.  It looks exactly like the pentagram created by `CompleteGraph[5]`.  Is that correct?

Comment: 0 in matrix considered as edge with weight 0. Op may means A /. {0 -> Infinity} for weighted adjacency matrix.  Also DegreeCentrality is nothing to do with edge weights.

Comment: @Szabolcs - In your result, only the central vertex has four edges, the others only have 3.

Comment: @JasonB. I didn't originally notice that the OP wanted a complete graph with no self-loops, but some 0-weights.  `IGWeightedAdjacencyGraph` exists because I find it extremely annoying that `WeightedAdjacencyMatrix` uses `0` to represent missing connections but `WeightedAdjacencyGraph` uses `Infinity`.  Both `0` and `Infinity` make sense (in different cases), but at least these two should be exact inverses. `IGWeightedAdjacencyGraph` simply lets you choose what to use, and uses `0` by default.

Comment: @JasonB. Given the types of centralities OP wants to compute, it makes little sense to assign 0 weight to some edges ... I assume he wanted to put no edges to where the matrix entry was 0.

Comment: @halmir I would really love to see better support for weighted graphs in future versions.  I hope you guys will consider that for the next version.  I would rather use robust built-ins than having to implement (or interface to) stuff in IGraph/M ...

Comment: @halmir I would be happy to provide multiple example tasks that come up in my daily work and are painful with the current level of weight support.

Answer (score 6):

If you are working with weighted graphs, I highly recommend my package [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM), which makes this much easier in many situations. (Apologies to everyone else for bringing this up *yet* again.)

Here's a little demo:

```
A = {{0, 3, 7, 0, 0}, {3, 0, 6, 0, 0}, {7, 6, 0, 2, 1}, {0, 0, 2, 0, 4}, {0, 0, 1, 4, 0}};
```

Annoyed about having to replace zeros with infinities?  Use `IGWeightedAdjacencyGraph`.  It can use any matrix element as the notation for a missing connection. The default is `0` (or `0.`).

Let's also thicken those edges at the same time.

```
g = IGWeightedAdjacencyGraph[A, EdgeStyle -> Thick]
```

[image]

Visualize weight as edge colour:

```
Legended[
 IGEdgeMap[ColorData["SolarColors"], EdgeStyle -> Rescale@*IGEdgeProp[EdgeWeight], g],
 BarLegend[{"SolarColors", MinMax@IGEdgeProp[EdgeWeight][g]}]
]
```

[image]

Visualize weight as edge thichkness:

```
IGEdgeMap[AbsoluteThickness, EdgeStyle -> IGEdgeProp[EdgeWeight], g]
```

[image]

I assume that when you mentioned `DegreeCentrality`, you wanted the *strength* of each vertex, i.e. the sum of edge weights for their incident edges. IGraph/M has that:

```
IGVertexStrength[g]
(* {10, 9, 16, 6, 5} *)
```

Want to scale vertices accordingly?

```
IGVertexMap[0.03 # &, VertexSize -> IGVertexStrength, g]
```

[image]

The built-in [`ClosenessCentrality`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ClosenessCentrality.html) does support weights, but [`BetweennessCentrality`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BetweennessCentrality.html) does not.  IGraph/M has both, with weights support (based on the [igraph](http://igraph.org/) library).

```
IGCloseness[g]
(* {0.037037, 0.0416667, 0.0625, 0.0454545, 0.0526316} *)

IGBetweenness[g]
(* {0., 0., 5., 0., 0.} *)
```

In both these functions (as well as in the built-in `ClosenessCentrality`), the edge weights are used directly in the shortest path calculations as the length of an edge.  They are not transformed (e.g. inverted) in any way.

If you want to construct a new graph with inverted edge weights, a simple way is

```
IGEdgeMap[1/# &, EdgeWeight, g]
```

Verify the result:

```
IGEdgeProp[EdgeWeight][%]
(* {1/3, 1/7, 1/6, 1/2, 1, 1/4} *)
```

If you want to remove weights, you can use `IGUnweighted`.  To test if a graph is edge-weighted, use `IGEdgeWeightedQ` (and note that the builtin [`WeightedGraphQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WeightedGraphQ.html) would return `True` for a non-edge weighted vertex weighted graph).

There are several other functions in IGraph/M which are useful with weighted graphs, or provide some advantage over the built-in equivalent when weights are present. E.g. `IGReverseGraph` correctly preserves edge weights while [`ReverseGraph`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReverseGraph.html) does not.

I also accept suggestions for new features/functions, especially as they relate to weighted graphs, which I use myself extensively.